# Attempt at proving a proposition about the conjugate of the Wigner Transform,where is my mistake?$\overline{W(f,g)}=W(g,f)?$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Edit,this is the exact phrasing of the question

> I define the Wigner Transform as follows,it is the fourier transform
> of the fourier-wigner transform Here is the question Here is the exact
> phrasing of the question For all Swartz Functions $f$ and $g$ on
> $\mathbb{R^n}$
>
> $W(f,g)(x,z)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}e^{-iz.p}f(x+p/2)\overline{g(x-p/2)}dp$.where
> $x,z\in\mathbb{R^n}$

> I want to show that $\overline{W(f,g)}=W(g,f)?$
> Here is my Attempt at the question
> [image: Proposition about the Conjugate of the Wigner Transform]

Here is my attempt at the question
[image: My Unsuccessful Attempt at the problem]
Could someone point out my mistake please?I hope my pictures are readable?

I was thinking about using the adjoint formula for the fourier transform but the bar is for conjugate,not the fourier transform?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), rather than images, to show your work.

Comment: Sorry I am very bad(or not the worst) at latex and if I do my question is not understanable,please I need some help?@Laufen